# Why is my C Matrix Generating 50x50?

Tags: c

I'm working on a connect4 type game (with n user defined rows/columns/pieces in a row to win). It must be initialized through the command line from a make file, such as: `./connectn.out 3 3 3`   where `3 3 3` represent rows/cols/pieces in a row to win. When I run this I get a matrix of 50x50, rather than a 3x3! I'm wondering if the issue lies in the command line argument code. The book I'm using only has examples using `char rowStr[100]= ""` where I think it should really be an `int`? I'm not going to be inputting anything but ints into the command line so I'm not sure the char is necessary.

Here's some code from the main.c file. I'm thinking the issue may lie in the `int numRows = *rowStr;` perhaps? Maybe because I'm defining the `int` as an array that's giving me 50 instead of 3?

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {

  char rowStr[100] = "";  // Number of rows
  char colStr[100] = "";  // Number of columns
  char toWinStr[100] = ""; //Number of pieces in a row to win

  if (argc < 4) {
    printf("Not enough arguments entered\n"
               "Usage connectn.out numRows numCols\n"
               "numToWin\n");
    return 1; // 1 indicates error
  }else if (argc > 4) {
    printf("Too many arguments entered\n"
               "Usage connectn.out numRows numCols\n"
               "numToWin\n");
    return 1; // 1 indicates error
  }

  // Grab inputs from command line
  strcpy(rowStr, argv[1]);
  strcpy(colStr, argv[2]);
  strcpy(toWinStr, argv[3]);

  // Output result

  const char blankSpace = '*'; //easier to show a blank space as a *
  int numRows= *rowStr; //User defined
  int numCols= *colStr; //User defined
  int numToWin= *toWinStr; //User defined
  const char pieces[] = "XO";
  char **board = createBoard(numRows, numCols, blankSpace);
  int rowPlayed, colPlayed;
  int playerTurn = 0; //0 means player1, 1 means player 2

  //Here's a bunch of functions
  while (!isGameOver(board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace,        numToWin)) {
    displayBoard(board, numRows, numCols);
    getMove(board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace, &rowPlayed, &colPlayed);
    makeMove(board, rowPlayed, colPlayed, pieces[playerTurn]);
    playerTurn = changeTurn(playerTurn);
  }

  declareWinnerorTie(playerTurn, board, numRows, numCols, blankSpace, numToWin);
  cleanUp(&board, numRows, numCols);

  return 0;

  }
```

Here is code from the board.c file, where the board is created. If the numRows and numCols are const int and set to a number, such as 3, it prints out perfectly fine.

Any ideas on how I can get my user input to correctly make the matrix size?

```
void displayBoard(char **board, int numRows, int numCols) {
  //print board
  for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    printf("%d ", row);
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
      printf("%c ", board[row][col]);
    }
    printf("\n");
  }
  //Print column headers
  printf("  ");
  for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
    printf("%d ", col);
  }
  printf("\n");
}

char **createBoard(int numRows, int numCols, const char blankSpace) {
  char **board = (char **) malloc(numRows * sizeof(char *));
  for (int row = 0; row < numRows; ++row) {
    board[row] = (char *) malloc(numCols * sizeof(char));
    for (int col = 0; col < numCols; ++col) {
      board[row][col] = blankSpace;
    }
  }
  return board;
}
```

Here's a truncated picture of what's displaying when I run the program from the command line. [50x50MatrixBoard](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ls0jc.png)

Comment: This line `char rowStr[100] = ""; // Number of rows` followed by `strcpy(rowStr, argv[1]);` and by `int numRows= *rowStr; //User defined` say you should throw that book into the sea, where it will be recycled by codefish.

Comment: So it is from the char designation. Thanks! I need to figure out a way to use int type as the command line argument and perhaps use scanf instead of strcpy then?

Comment: That would be `sscanf`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int numRows= *rowStr; //User defined 
int numCols= *colStr; //User defined 
int numToWin= *toWinStr; //User defined
```

You are asigning first char of rowStr, colStr, toWinStr to integer type variables, the reason you are getting 50 instead of 3, please take look at the value of ASCII number 3 at [this table](http://www.asciitable.com/)

What you need here is

```
int numRows= atoi(rowStr); //User defined 
int numCols= atoi(colStr); //User defined 
int numToWin= atoi(toWinStr); //User define
```

with `#include <stdlib.h>`

Comment: That makes a lot of sense! Do you know how I can make it actually a '3'? My confusion lies in the actual command line process. My book and professor showed us that the way to do it is the way I have (with char* argv[]). Setting it equal to the int was my attempt to do something.

Comment: Edit: I removed the & and it worked! Thanks so much!